# Using dataclasses with dependent attributes via property

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I have a class, for example `Circle`, which has dependent attributes, `radius` and `circumference`. It makes sense to use a `dataclass` here because of the boilerplate for `__init__`, `__eq__`, `__repr__` and the ordering methods (`__lt__`, ...).

I choose one of the attributes to be dependent on the other, e.g. the circumference is computed from the radius. Since the class should support initialization with either of the attributes (+ have them included in `__repr__` as well as `dataclasses.asdict`) I annotate both:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import math


@dataclass
class Circle:
    radius: float = None
    circumference: float = None

    @property
    def circumference(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.radius

    @circumference.setter
    def circumference(self, val):
        if val is not type(self).circumference:  # <-- awkward check
            self.radius = val / (2 * math.pi)
```

This requires me to add the somewhat awkward check for `if val is not type(self).circumference` because this is what the setter will receive if no value is provided to `__init__`.

Then if I wanted to make the class hashable by declaring `frozen=True` I need to change `self.radius = ...` to `object.__setattr__(self, 'radius', ...)` because otherwise this would attempt to assign to a field of a frozen instance.

So my question is if this is a sane way of using dataclasses together with properties or if potential (non-obvious) obstacles lie ahead and I should refrain from using dataclasses in such cases? Or maybe there is even a better way of achieving this goal?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you could set the attributes in the `__init__` method as follows:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar
import math


@dataclass(frozen=True, order=True)
class CircleWithFrozenDataclass:
    radius: float = 0
    circumference: float = 0

    def __init__(self, radius=0, circumference=0):
        super().__init__()
        if circumference:
            object.__setattr__(self, 'circumference', circumference)
            object.__setattr__(self, 'radius', circumference / (2 * math.pi))
        if radius:
            object.__setattr__(self, 'radius', radius)
            object.__setattr__(self, 'circumference', 2 * math.pi * radius)
```

This will still provide you with all the helpful `__eq__`, `__repr__`, `__hash__`, and ordering method injections. While `object.__setattr__` looks ugly, note that the [CPython implementation itself uses `object.__setattr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/dataclasses.py#L401-L408) to set attributes when injecting the generated `__init__` method for a frozen `dataclass`.

If you really want to get rid of `object.__setattr__`, you can set `frozen=False` (the default) and override the `__setattr__` method yourself. This is copying how the `frozen` feature of dataclasses is [implemented in CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/dataclasses.py#L553-L558). Note that you will also have to turn on `unsafe_hash=True` as `__hash__` is no longer injected since `frozen=False`.

```
@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True, order=True)
class CircleUsingDataclass:
    radius: float = 0
    circumference: float = 0

    _initialized: InitVar[bool] = False

    def __init__(self, radius=0, circumference=0):
        super().__init__()
        if circumference:
            self.circumference = circumference
            self.radius = circumference / (2 * math.pi)
        if radius:
            self.radius = radius
            self.circumference = 2 * math.pi * radius
        self._initialized = True

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if self._initialized and \
            (type(self) is __class__ or name in ['radius', 'circumference']):
            raise AttributeError(f"cannot assign to field {name!r}")
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

    def __delattr__(self, name, value):
        if self._initialized and \
            (type(self) is __class__ or name in ['radius', 'circumference']):
            raise AttributeError(f"cannot delete field {name!r}")
        super().__delattr__(name, value)
```

In my opinion, freezing should only happen after the `__init__` by default, but for now I will probably use the first approach.