# How can you use property setter when using frozen dataclasses in Python

Tags: python, abstract-class, python-3.7, python-dataclasses, frozenset

I was just playing around with the concept of Python dataclasses and abstract classes and what i am trying to achieve is basically create a frozen dataclass but at the same time have one attribute as a property. Below is my code for doing so:

```py
import abc
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


class AbsPersonModel(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def age(self):
        ...

    @age.setter
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def age(self, value):
        ...

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def multiply_age(self, factor):
        ...


@dataclass(order=True, frozen=True)
class Person(AbsPersonModel):
    sort_index: int = field(init=False, repr=False)
    name: str
    lastname: str
    age: int
    _age: int = field(init=False, repr=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.sort_index = self.age

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        if value < 0 or value > 100:
            raise ValueError("Non sensical age cannot be set!")
        self._age = value

    def multiply_age(self, factor):
        return self._age * factor


if __name__ == "__main__":
    persons = [
        Person(name="Jack", lastname="Ryan", age=35),
        Person(name="Jason", lastname="Bourne", age=45),
        Person(name="James", lastname="Bond", age=60)
    ]

    sorted_persons = sorted(persons)
    for person in sorted_persons:
        print(f"{person.name} and {person.age}")
```

When i run this i get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "abstract_prac.py", line 57, in <module>
    Person(name="Jack", lastname="Ryan", age=35),
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "abstract_prac.py", line 48, in age
    self._age = value
  File "<string>", line 3, in __setattr__
dataclasses.FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field '_age'
```

How can i get the best of both worlds(dataclasses and also using property along with it)?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I will repeat my comment from your [latter question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59222092/2750819). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57791679/2750819: while the answer primarily deals with `__init__`, the same applies for `__post_init__` (as in the CPython implemenation, internally `__init__` calls `__post_init__`).

Answer (score 4):

You can do what the `frozen` initialisator [in dataclasses itself does](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/793cb85437299a3da3d74fe65480d720af330cbb/Lib/dataclasses.py#L400-L409) and use `object.__setattr__` to assign values. Given your abstract class, this dataclass definition should work:

```py
@dataclass(order=True, frozen=True)
class Person:
    sort_index: int = field(init=False, repr=False)
    name: str
    lastname: str
    age: int
    _age: int = field(init=False, repr=False)  # can actually be omitted

    def __post_init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'sort_index', self.age)

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        if value < 0 or value > 100:
            raise ValueError("Non sensical age cannot be set!")
        object.__setattr__(self, '_age', value)

    def multiply_age(self, factor):
        return self._age * factor
```

Running your test suite should now return the expected

```
Jack and 35
Jason and 45
James and 60
```

This works because setting a dataclass to `frozen` disables that class' own `__setattr__` and makes it just raise the exception you saw. Any `__setattr__` of its superclasses (which always includes `object`) will still work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, assigning to the property setter just raises `FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field 'age'`

Comment: Still works for me. I fixed up my sample code so that it can copy-pasted more easily, I guess something got mixed up while applying the fix to the initial question's code.

Answer (score 0):

I know maybe this answer is more generic, but it could help as it's more simple than the other answer, and **doesn't use any getter or setter**
Simply use `__post_init__`

```
import random
from dataclasses import dataclass, FrozenInstanceError

@dataclass(repr=True, eq=True, order=False, unsafe_hash=False, frozen=True)
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'age', self.calc_age())
    @staticmethod
    def calc_age():
        return random.randint(0, 100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    person = Person("Fede")
    person2 = Person("Another")
    print(person)
    print(person2)
    try:
        person.age = 1
    except FrozenInstanceError:
        print("can't set age ")
```