# Python frozen dataclass, allow changing of attribute via method

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Suppose I have a dataclass:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foo:
    id: str
    name: str
```

I want this to be immutable (hence the `frozen=True`), such that `foo.id = bar` and `foo.name = baz` fail. But, I want to be able to strip the id, like so:

```
foo = Foo(id=10, name="spam")

foo.strip_id()
foo
-> Foo(id=None, name="spam")
```

I have tried a few things, overriding **setattr**, but nothing worked. Is there an elegant solution to this? (I know I could write a method that returns a new frozen instance that is identical except that that id has been stripped, but that seems a bit hacky, and it would require me to do `foo = foo.strip_id()`, since `foo.strip_id()` would not actually change `foo`)

Edit:

Although some commenters seem to disagree, I think there is a legitimate distinction between 'fully mutable, do what you want with it', and 'immutable, except in this particular, tightly controlled way'

Comment: You want it to be immutable, except that you want it to be mutable. There's a fundamental contradiction in your goals here.

Comment: `foo = foo.strip_id()` is a perfectly fine thing to do. It's how string methods work, for example.

Comment: You can't have mutable, immutable objects. Sorry. Choose one. Also: "I know I could write a method that returns a new frozen instance that is identical except that that id has been stripped, but that seems a bit hacky" That isn't hacky *at all*. Indeed, that is generally considered best practice, there are entire languages that prevent mutable state, and this is how objects work in those languages. I would go with that route.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can do it by <strike>directly modifying the `__dict__` member of the instance</strike> modifying the attribute using `object.__setattr__(...)`<sup>1</sup>, but why??? Asking specifically for *immutable* and then making it mutable is... indecisive. But if you must:

```python
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foo:
    id: str
    name: str
    def strip_id(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'id', None)

foo=Foo(10, 'bar')

>>> foo
Foo(id=10, name='bar')
>>> foo.strip_id()
>>> foo
Foo(id=None, name='bar')
```

Any way of doing this is probably going to seem hacky... because it requires doing things that are fundamentally the opposite of the design.

If you're using this as a signal to other programmers that they should not modify the values, the way that is normally done in Python is by prefixing the variable name with a single underscore. If you want to do that, while also making the values accessible, Python has a builtin module called `property`, where (from the documentation) "typical use is to define a managed attribute":

```python
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
    _name: str
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value
    @name.deleter
    def name(self):
        self._name = None
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
>>> f=Foo()
>>> f.name = "bar"
>>> f.name
'bar'
>>> f._name
'bar'
>>> del f.name
>>> f.name
>>> f._name
```

The decorated methods hide the actual value of `_name` behind `name` to control how the user interacts with that value. You can use this to apply transformation rules or validation checks to data before it is stored or returned.

This doesn't quite accomplish the same thing as using `@dataclass(frozen=True)`, and if you try declaring it as frozen, you'll get an error. Mixing frozen dataclasses with the property decorator is not straightforward and I have not seen a satisfying solution that is concise and intuitive. @Arne posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59249252/6689725), and I found [this thread](https://github.com/florimondmanca/www/issues/102) on GitHub, but neither approach is very inspiring; if I came across such things in code that I had to maintain, I would not be very happy (but I *would* be confused, and probably pretty irritated).

---

<sub>1: Modified as per the answer by @Arne, who observed that the internal use of a dictionary as the data container is not guaranteed.</sub>

Comment: This does work, thank you. I've edited my question to make the same comment, but surely there is a reasonable difference between 'mutable in a very specific, tightly controlled way', and 'totally mutable'?

Comment: Not really. I mean, who are you trying to protect things from? Are you, by chance, coming from a Java background, and looking for something more like class private members?

Comment: Nope, no java background. It's for an internal company library, and this object should only rarely be changed, and only in this particular way. I'm protecting against library users misusing the data type, which would introduce a security issue.

Comment: If it's just to keep other programmers from incorrectly using this piece of data, then the way that is traditionally communicated in Python is to prefix the variable name with an underscore (single underscore, we're not making dunders here). That is usually understood to mean "private, don't modify" and it will also prevent it from being imported with a wildcard import.

Comment: Fair enough, but this is a dataclass explicilty designed to store the id and the name, so making one of them private with an underscore seems just as hacky

Comment: you could use the `_` prefix to mark them private, and then add getter methods that return those values. basically: `def get_id(self): return self._id`

Comment: @Z4-tier no, don't use getters in Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga normally I agree with that, but in this case it seems like an acceptable way to meet the requirement of "somewhat private". Is there another pattern that would work better?

Comment: @Z4-tier use a `property`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I added an update to this discussing the option of using `@property` decorators, but in the context of the original question, I can't find any way of using `@property` with frozen dataclasses. At least, I can't find a way that is clean and won't lead to rage on the part of whoever has to support it. Do you know a good way of doing this?

Comment: @alex_halford it's reasonable to want this functionality for things like members that serve as a cache for expensive to derive data that can always be derived from the other members, or things like mutexes. This is why C++ has the `mutable` keyword. You can do type backflips to avoid it but you aren't crazy for wanting it.

Answer (score 5):

As a slight improvement over Z4-tier's solution, please use `object.__setattr__` instead of `self.__dict__` to manipulate attributes of a frozen dataclass. The fact that classes use a dictionary to store their attributes is just the default behavior, and dataclasses in particular will regularly use `__slots__` instead because it reduces the memory footprint.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foo:
    id: str
    name: str

    def strip_id(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'a', None)
```

Comment: I added this to my answer, but upvoting as it's a good observation.